# Does anyone know why on small device like phone this columns don't work correct with Bootstrap 5?

Tags: html, css, responsive, bootstrap-5, col

[Why columns still take 100% width when I switch to phone size screen? They should take 50% width. Is anyone can explain why Grid system don't working?]

https://www.codeply.com/p/9Jl5QXIYZs

Comment: Which columns are you talking about, some seem to be responsive but other's not?

Comment: I mean yellow ones, they are not responsive for Phone screen, they should be 50/50, but they keep 100% width

Comment: The prefix for screen widths less than 576px is `col-`. Try adding `col-6` to cover all options.

Comment: Just to add on to what @phuzi is saying, I'm not sure you realise that the column sizes are going up in size. So col-sm-6 is only applied on 576px OR MORE, not the other way around.